# Getting black screen when setting wallpaper using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, user32

I was using the below code to programaticaly set my desktop wallpaper in VB.NET

```
    Private Const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER As Integer = &H14
    Private Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE As Integer = &H1
    Private Const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = &H2
    Private Declare Auto Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer


    Sub Main()

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "result.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)

    End Sub
```

It was working fine earlier. But now when i run it, it sets my desktop as black, instead of setting the image and I am not able to find out why. Does anyone know why this happens? Does this method have any dependency?

Comment: Path to `result.jpg` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that since my wallpaper is in same folder it would automatically pick up. I was wrong. Now i remember that earlier i tried with full path. Thank you